# JRE upgrade, Migrate SSL certificates

Tags: java, security, java-8, ssl-certificate, keytool

Need to upgrade java version, but several certificates have been added into the keystore from time to time. How to migrate to new java version with these certificates. Excepted answer to do it in production from experienced folks in the community.

Comment: If you have all of the certs then a simple script should do it.  Are you looking for the command?  Do you have all of the certs?

Comment: I am looking for these steps
How to backup all the certificates from old jre ?
How to restore all the certificates to new jre ?
Handle conflicts .or will there be no conflicts as new jre may have its own certificates
Will I have to exclude expired certificates